# JavascriptMVC failing cookbook examble

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc

I'm working with JavascriptMVC but fail to get [the following example](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/cookbook.creating.html#section_PageSetup) working. I've followed it all step by step. The page 'does' show up but all I see is the **recipes** heading. When I use firebug I do see the following code present:

```
<h2>Recipes</h2>
<ul id="recipes"></ul>
<form id="create"></form>
```

However the form, nor the items show up. I've tried the latest Firefox stable build, Arora, the latest google chroom and internet explorer on Windows 8.1. Has anyone else run into this problem? I would ask on their forums but the registering web page is not working.

For reference this is my command while building the project:

```
I:\stage\analyse\bijlagen\voorbeelden\javascriptmvc>js jmvc/generate/app cookbook
      cookbook/cookbook.js
      cookbook/cookbook.less
      cookbook/cookbook.md
      cookbook/cookbook_test.js
      cookbook/index.html
      cookbook/test.html
      cookbook/models/fixtures/fixtures.js
      cookbook/scripts/build.html
      cookbook/scripts/build.js
      cookbook/scripts/clean.js
      cookbook/scripts/crawl.js
      cookbook/scripts/docs.js

I:\stage\analyse\bijlagen\voorbeelden\javascriptmvc>js jmvc/generate/scaffold cookbook/models/recipe
      cookbook/models/recipe.js
      cookbook/models/recipe_test.js
      cookbook/cookbook_test.js (steal added)
      cookbook/models/fixtures/fixtures.js (code added)
      cookbook/recipe/create/create.html
      cookbook/recipe/create/create.js
      cookbook/recipe/create/create_test.js
      cookbook/recipe/create/init.ejs
      cookbook/recipe/create/test.html
      cookbook/recipe/list/init.ejs
      cookbook/recipe/list/list.html
      cookbook/recipe/list/list.js
      cookbook/recipe/list/list_test.js
      cookbook/recipe/list/test.html
      cookbook/cookbook_test.js (steal added)
      cookbook/cookbook_test.js (steal added)
      cookbook/cookbook.js (steal added)
      cookbook/cookbook.js (steal added)
      cookbook/cookbook.js (code added)
      cookbook/index.html (html added)
      cookbook/cookbook_test.js (code added)
```

Comment: Will you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code?

Comment: @eebbesen I would but it can't be done so easily. JavascriptMVC is a collection of multiple small tools with a lot of folders and dependency managers. It's the exact same starting example as displayed in my link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing happen to me too. The warning in the tutorial about chrome made me believe that other browsers (like IE, which I tested) did not have that problem, but it seems they do.

Either way, I put "--allow-file-access-from-files" as a launch parameter for chrome and it worked properly.

Comment: I will test this later this week. If I can confirm this as a fix for Firefox to I will mark your answer as the correct one so it might help other people.